# Initializing properties in the primary constructor of a Kotlin data class

Tags: kotlin, class, constructor, initialization

I'm working on a Kotlin project that needs to work with 'rational' numbers. To do that I have a class that stores a rational number as two integers (numerator and denominator) and performs some arithmetic using those values. The problem I am running into is that one of the requirements is that the values be normalized. An incoming value of 2/4 should be stored as 1/2, 6/8 should be 1/4, and so on. I also want to make this a 'data class' so I can take advantage of the built-in equals and hashcode functions.

My class looks like this:

```
data class Rational(val numerator: BigInteger, val denominator: BigInteger): Comparable<Rational>
{
    init {
        if(denominator.equals(0))
        {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("0 is not a valid denominator")
        }

        //normalize the value by reducing to the least common denominator
        val gcd = numerator.gcd(denominator)
        this.numerator = numerator.div(gcd)
        this.denominator = denominator.div(gcd)

    }
}

infix fun BigInteger.divBy(d: BigInteger): Rational
{
    return Rational(this, d)
}

fun main() {

    val half = 2 divBy 4
    println(half) // expected: Rational(numerator=1, denominator=2)
}
```

which doesn't compile since the parameters are 'val'. I don't want to make the properties mutable, but I'm not sure how else to do the calculation before setting the value. I can't remove the modifiers because they are required for a data class.

What is the procedure for initializing properties that need to be processed before the values are set? The only answer I have been able to find so far is this: [How to store temporary variable while initializing a Kotlin object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859938/how-to-store-temporary-variable-while-initializing-a-kotlin-object) which appears to be for an old (pre 1.0) version of kotlin.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this in the primary constructor of a data class.  If you do it in a secondary constructor, or make the class non-data, or both, you can do it.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Do you know of a good example of using a secondary constructor to do something like this? All the examples I have found assume either static variables: constructor(a,b): this("1", "2") or simple inline operations: constructor(a,b): this(a+b, "ba")

Comment: Never mind.  You can't _quite_ do it with a data class, since the public constructor and the desired input constructor have the same signature.  There's also, of course, no way to prevent `copy` from screwing up your invariants.  You have to drop the `data` from the class.

Comment: FWIW, my own Rational class (doesn't everyone write one of these?) is just an ordinary class.  After all, once you've overridden `equals()`, `hashCode()`, `toString()`, and maybe `component0()` and `component1()` (all one-liners) then there's not much benefit from a data class — and you don't want a `copy()` here anyway.  (If you're so minded, you can also implement `Comparable` and `Number`, arithmetic operators, calculated properties, extension functions for creating instances from other numerical types, extension operators…  It's a fun exercise!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is not directly possible. By design, a data class is a simple data holder. If we pass a value to it, we expect it to hold exactly this value. Transforming the value on-the-fly may be considered an unexpected behavior. Maybe it would be better to provide a `normalized()` member function or a factory function?

Having said that, we can cheat it a little by hiding the primary constructor and providing `invoke()` operator for the companion object:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    println(Rational(4.toBigInteger(), 8.toBigInteger())) // Rational(numerator=1, denominator=2)
}

data class Rational private constructor(val numerator: BigInteger, val denominator: BigInteger) {
    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(numerator: BigInteger, denominator: BigInteger): Rational {
            if(denominator.equals(0))
            {
                throw IllegalArgumentException("0 is not a valid denominator")
            }

            //normalize the value by reducing to the least common denominator
            val gcd = numerator.gcd(denominator)
            return Rational(numerator.div(gcd), denominator.div(gcd))
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this is not entirely what you asked for. We don't use the constructor here, but a function which looks like a constructor. Also, we need to remember about the `copy()` function which doesn't do normalization and I believe we can't overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this later, I ended up changing to a non-data class and implementing the equals and hashmap functions myself. The final result looks like this:

```
class Rational ( numerator: BigInteger,  denominator: BigInteger): Comparable<Rational>
{
    private val numerator: BigInteger
    private val denominator: BigInteger
    init {
        require(denominator!=BigInteger.ZERO)
        {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("0 is not a valid denominator")
        }

        //normalize the value by reducing to the least common denominator and simplifying negation
        val sign: BigInteger = denominator.signum().toBigInteger()

        val gcd = numerator.gcd(denominator)
        this.numerator = sign * numerator.div(gcd)
        this.denominator = sign * denominator.div(gcd)
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        if(denominator == BigInteger.valueOf(1))
        {
            return numerator.toString()
        }
        return "$numerator/$denominator"
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as Rational

        if (numerator != other.numerator) return false
        if (denominator != other.denominator) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = numerator.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + denominator.hashCode()
        return result
    }
}
```